# Manage ArrayList in jquery and print exit in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

what i wanted to do is use jquery to get data from the databases and show it in the jsp pages.

In my jsp:

```
<input onclick="getPlatform('${item.string1}')"type="radio" id="${item.string1}" name="tab-group-1" checked>
```

in my .js:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Controller?operation=GetPlatforms",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json",
    //if received a response from the server
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        //our platform was correct so we have some information to display
        if (data.success) {
            $.each(data.PlatformInfo, function() {
                $("#ajaxResponsePlatforms").html("");
                $("#ajaxResponsePlatforms").append("value: " + data.PlatformInfo.name);
            });
        }
        //display error message
        else {
            $("#ajaxResponsePlatforms").html("<div><b>Country code is Invalid!</b></div>");
        }
    },
```

the server output is:

```
value of JsonElement: [{"name":"PC"},{"name":"Servers"}]
value of myObj: {"success":true,"PlatformInfo":[{"name":"PC"},{"name":"Servers"}]}
```

and the result in my JSP pages is:

```
value: undefined
```

Code to build Json response:

```
String technology = request.getParameter("technology");
            System.out.println("Test " + technology);
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.setHeader("Expires", "-1");

            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();


            BACENGQueryDatabases PlatformData = new BACENGQueryDatabases();
            ArrayList PlatformInfo = PlatformData.GetPlatform(technology);
            JsonElement platformObj = gson.toJsonTree(PlatformInfo);

            System.out.println("JsonElement: " + platformObj);


            if (PlatformInfo.isEmpty()) {
                myObj.addProperty("success", false);
                System.out.println("Array empty");
            } else {
                myObj.addProperty("success", true);
                System.out.println("Array full");
            }
            System.out.println("value json " + platformObj);
            myObj.add("PlatformInfo", platformObj);
            out.println(myObj.toString());
            System.out.println(" myObj: " + myObj.toString());
            out.close();
```

It's happenign since I want to do get the result as ArraList form, however if instead Array I use a single String object it is working fine.

how can use ArayList and jquery.apped method?

Comment: Please post the relevant Java code where you build your JSON response.

Comment: Done, I've included the code where the Json is builded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use `$.each` on `data.PlatformInfo` you shoud use what's iterated on inside the callback, not `data.PlatformInfo` which is a list (and has no `.name`), something like this:

```
$.each(data.PlatformInfo, function(i, e) { // i = index, e = element
    // are you sure you want to: $("#ajaxResponsePlatforms").html("");
    $("#ajaxResponsePlatforms").append("value: " + e.name);
});
```

Also note that setting html content to `""` **inside** the loop is probably not what you want, you probably want that before the `$.each`.

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/RdeHm/)

Comment: Great!! It's exactly what I was looking for. would be possible to add an action (ej: onclick="fuction()") for each value created in my jsp. In this case an action for PC and Servers?

Comment: I'm trying with this code but it seems like the argument is empty `$("#ajaxResponsePlatforms").append("<ul onclick=getPlatformGI("+e.name+")>"+e.name+"</ul>");` Have you any idea what is worng?

Comment: Ok, I got it, I miss a `'` in my code. the final line is: `$("#ajaxResponsePlatforms").append("<ul onclick=getPlatform('"+e.name+"')>"+e.name+"</ul>");`

Comment: What about if I have this kind of Json object: `[{"Nnodes":"163"},{"Commnet":"windows Machine"}]` how could I to show those different value in my JSP in different line, something like that: `Number of nodes value: 163` `Comment: windows machine`